# C++ if statement error on string

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I know I'm sounding an awful lot like a newb by asking this however I'm curious as to know why I'm getting an error when using simple operators through an if statement on a string? Here is what I am doing to produce the error:

```
    void Shift (string updown )
{
    if (updown == "hel")
    {
        //random code
    }
}
```

and my includes would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: what is the error? Also, using namespace is frowned upon.

Comment: It's not frowned upon (except in .h files and some other cases). using namespace is the best way to make the code manageable and readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you know, try to include the `<string>` header. And either write `std::string` or add a `using std::string` after the include.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Sorry I can't vote it up I don't yet have 15 rep, but I will when i get it!

Comment: @tincopper2 lemme do it for you, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot

```
#include <string>
```

Other header files might include the internal header that provides the `std::string` class, but without the associated functions such as the `==` operator you're missing.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Sorry I can't vote it up I don't yet have 15 rep, but I will when i get it!

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use the std::string class without actually including the necessary header.

Add `#include <string>` to your list of includes.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Sorry I can't vote it up I don't yet have 15 rep, but I will when i get it!